# Having trouble with auto-scroll on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less

```js
.element {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

When dragging the child element towards the bottom / top of the page in IE, it is unresponsive and auto scroll doesn't happen at times.
I have tried "-ms-overflow-y : scroll" but that did work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is related to the `overflow-x: hidden;` CSS property.

I have created a [sample](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/PoZmpgb) using your CSS style, it seems that after removing the `overflow-x: hidden;` CSS property, it could be scrolled bottom of the page in IE browser.

[image]

So, try to remove the `overflow-x: hidden;` CSS property.

It still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).